# How can I add parameters to my CosmosDB Data Explorer workbooks?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-explorer

I have a CosmosDB Data Explorer workbook with a set of functional predefined queries. The workbook offers real benefits by improving efficiency when our organization needs to run some useful queries against when debugging our data/applications. The one draw back is that its prone to failure via user error.

As of now, users need to edit the cells, replacing query values for those that match their needs before running the cells. This is not optimal as it introduces the opportunity that the queries could be broken unintentionally by an unwitting user should they save an erroneous query, hence erasing record of the working query.

One of the queries looks as follows:

```
%%sql --database DatabaseName --container ContainerName
SELECT c.propertyOne, c.propertyTwo, SUM(c.propertyForSummation)
FROM c 
WHERE c.propertyOne = "XYZ123" 
 AND c.propertyTwo = 1 
 AND c.timestamp >= '2021-07-15'
 AND c.lastUpdatedTimestamp <= '2021-07-16'
GROUP BY c.propertyOne, c.propertyTwo
```

**I'd like to introduce parameter fields {propertyOne, propertyTwo, timestamp, lastUpdatedTimestamp}, so the query would look as below for future users of the workbook to avoid the previously stated scenario. Is that possible?**

```
%%sql --database DatabaseName --container ContainerName
SELECT c.propertyOne, c.propertyTwo, SUM(c.propertyForSummation)
FROM c 
WHERE c.propertyOne = @propertyOne 
 AND c.propertyTwo = @propertyTwo 
 AND c.timestamp >= @timestamp
 AND c.lastUpdatedTimestamp <= @lastUpdatedTimestamp
GROUP BY c.propertyOne, c.propertyTwo
```

*I'm aware how to do this in Azure Data Studio (ADS) workbooks, but unfortunately can not see the option in Data Explorer, and am unaware of the possibility to connect to CosmosDb from ADS*

Comment: can you give a little more concrete info about what the workbook does/what the queries are like, etc?  workbooks does support parameters, but depending on what your data sources are, etc how you use them is different.

in general, workbooks cannot query cosmosdb *instances*, workbooks can query metadata/resource information *about* cosmosdb instances, or metrics for those resources.

Comment: @JohnGardner - you can query CosmosDb from data explorer workbooks. I'm doing it. As stated in the post the workbook context is Data Explorer (NOT Data Studio). If I learn of a way to configure CosmosDb as a data source in Data Studio that might change, but until then I'm working in Data Explorer.

Comment: then i'm confused about what this is, because it is tagged [`azure-monitor-workbooks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview) which is an entirely different product, nor is "cosmos db data explorer" (a tool) the same thing as [`azure-data-explorer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/) (another kind of DB service altogether).  I'm going to remove both of those tags as they seem to not actually be what this post is about?

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you'd stop removing that tag. What I'm trying to figure out is how to add parameters, and use them in my queries, in a workbook. That workbook is accessible via the Data Explorer tab and only in the context of a specific CosmosDb account.

Comment: yes, but it isn't an "Azure-monitor-workbook", which is another *unrelated* product to your question.  It would be like adding excel tag to it because excel also has the word workbook used in its product.  Azure Monitor Workbooks is a product, and this question is not referencing it, so i removed the tag.  Similarly, you added "Azure-data-explorer", which is another *unrelated product* to your question.  there's a *tool* in cosmosdb called "Data explorer" which is *not* Azure Data Explorer (the service)

Answer (score 0):

I also [posted the question in learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/498354/how-can-i-add-parameters-to-my-cosmosdb-data-explo.html) and it has been confirmed that the feature is not supported at this time (Aug.10th, 2021)